# How to get all past transactions in fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

As currently, I'm working on fabric SDKs. I want to get all the past transactions of fabric on the client-side.

Example: I already have 1 installed chain code. On fabric, I called delete_user and edit_user methods. I want those all transaction on client side without storing in offchain DB.

Can anyone suggest Node SDK method for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have each transaction function emit a suitably named chaincode event (such as "deleteUser" and "editUser"). The chaincode event gets emitted be peers only when the transaction is successfully committed and updates the ledger. Your client application can listen for those chaincode events and take action on each chaincode event.

You can start listening for chaincode events from a specific block number to replay historic events. You may also want to use a "checkpointer" (or roll-your-own) mechanism for persisting the block number and transaction ID your listener last successfully processed so you can resume listening from exactly the same point after an application restart. This would allow you to process each chaincode event exactly once, with no duplication or missed events.

See these Fabric samples for examples:

- https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-events
- https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/off_chain_data